# Gulp browser-sync not monitoring and injecting files

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, gulp, browser-sync

I have following directory structure

```
workspace
  |--dev
      |--proj
          |--css 
              |--style.css
          |--js
              |--app.js
          |index.php
          |something.html
          |gulpfile.js
          |package.json
```

I had installed `vhost` named as `dev.local` on `...workspace\dev`. As you can see I have created a `gulpfile.js` in my `proj` directory.

Now if I run `gulp browser-sync` command my browser window is open showing following url `http://dev.local:3000/proj/`. It perfectly opens my `index.php` page but if I do any modification in my files they are not monitored and are not injected into my page. So there is no auto reload of my page.

Here is my `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create(); // create a browser sync instance.

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    bs.init({
        open: 'external',
        host: 'dev.local',
        proxy: 'dev.local/proj'
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("*.html,*.php,css/*.css,js/*.js").on('change', bs.reload);
});
```

Here is the output of my terminal

```
gulp browser-sync
[12:14:12] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/workspace/dev/proj/gulpfile.js
[12:14:12] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[12:14:12] Finished 'browser-sync' after 15 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://dev.local
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/proj
    External: http://dev.local:3000/proj
 ------------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://dev.local:3001
 ------------------------------------------------
```

I had already searched SO for various solutions but of no avail. Please help I am stuck.

**UPDATE**

I am using BrowserSync version 2.18.8 and gulp version 3.9.1

Comment: First thing I'd do is change `bs.reload` to `function() { console.log('changed')  }` and see if it's a problem with the gulp watch or the bs.reload. Also which version of browsersync are you using, the docs suggest pre and post 2.- have different syntax

Comment: The 2.0 docs for get suggest you could call `bs.watch()` instead of `gulp.watch` if you wanted: https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-get worth a try?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald  `function() { console.log('changed') }` does not return any output on console

Comment: That suggests that either your glob path wotnots aren't right or that the event handler isn't being bound. Can you try `gulp.watch('<your files>, function() { console.log('changed'); });` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of i would suggest to split the watching tasks into multiple, makes it easier to maintain and update. By reading your comments i can suggest to reverse the chain of gulp.tasks. You are currently loading 'browser-sync' from your watch task, but you can load your 'watch' task from your browser-sync task.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create(); // create a browser sync instance.

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    bs.init({
        open: 'external',
        host: 'dev.local',
        proxy: 'dev.local/proj'
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', bs.reload);
    gulp.watch("*.php").on('change', bs.reload);
    gulp.watch("./css/*.css").on('change', bs.reload);
    gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on('change', bs.reload);

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'watch']);
```

Also modifying css files can be streamed by browser-sync,

```
    gulp.watch("css/*.css").on('change', bs.stream);
```

Next i would suggest to test weather or not the files are actually beeing monitored, and change the path of the gulp.watch tasks accordingly.
If you need help with this comment below.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had already gone through the documentation and seen how to inject the css by using stream. The problem is actually that the gulp does not continuously monitor the files.

Comment: i understand. Looking at your project setup i have updated my answer to use the required paths for css and js. Can you check this? 
Also from your example i cannot deduct if there are other .php files that need watching, i.e. the gulp.task will only watch 'any' files with the .php extention in the same directory level as your gulpfile, i.e. only in 'proj', not above not inside child directories.

Comment: Nope it does not monitor any files. The gulp just start once and finishes task immediately instead of continuously monitoring files. I know about how directory structure. Hence that is not the issue.

Comment: ok i get it, and i think its because you call gulp watch with ['browser-sync']. You can break those up into lets say 'serve' and 'watch' and have both tasks be loaded by the default gulp task. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now its working. But a little doubt as per my knowledge initializing must be done before. so I think `
gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function () {` will be better option than the specified one. Now we can call `gulp watch` which will first call  `serve`. Accordingly we can change last line.

Comment: If you try my version you only have to call gulp. Another approach would be chaining both tasks from default

Comment: If you call just gulp than it will call which task?

Comment: In this case it will call the default task, which will call serve, which will call watch

Comment: So I think the edited version will be better because it will execute / finish the tasks in following order serve> watch>default. So initialization is done first

Comment: That wont work. It will cause watch to end. You could chain both from default, first calling init for browsersync, secondly calling watch, ive edited my answer

Comment: I'm satisfied with your solution. However, just for information the edit which I have made was working perfectly and no such issue occurred during the execution of my test cases. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to hear. Prehaps you can update your question to also reflect the changed code, that way other people comming here will get a more complete answer.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this way? This is what I implemented in my application to finding the new uploaded images and resize and move to another folder.

This gulp code is watching new images from folder and reduce image size and move to scaled folder.

Probably it may helpful to you.

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
// include plug-ins
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var watch = require("gulp-watch");
var newer = require("gulp-newer");
var gulpgm = require("gulp-gm");

//var imgSource = './app/client/media/site/max/*';
//var imgDestination = './app/client/media/site/min';
var imgSource = [
    './app/client/media/**/*.png',
    './app/client/media/**/*.jpg',
    './app/client/media/**/*.jpeg',
    './app/client/media/**/*.gif',
    './app/client/media/**/**/*.png',
    './app/client/media/**/**/*.jpg',
    './app/client/media/**/**/*.jpeg',
    './app/client/media/**/**/*.gif',
    './app/client/media/**/**/**/*.png',
    './app/client/media/**/**/**/*.jpg',
    './app/client/media/**/**/**/*.jpeg',
    './app/client/media/**/**/**/*.gif',
];
var imgDestination = './app/client/scaled/';

gulp
        .task('imagemin', function () {
            console.log("image min called");
            return gulp.src(imgSource)
                    .pipe(watch(imgSource))
                    .pipe(newer(imgDestination))
                    .pipe(gulpgm(function (gmFile) {
                        return gmFile.minify();
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDestination));
        });
gulp
        .task("default", ["imagemin", "watch"]);

gulp
        .task("watch", function () {
            watch(imgSource, ["imagemin"]);
        });
```

Comment: This answer is unclear and does not explain what, why, how. -1

Comment: @DGRFDSGN: if you don't understand then it's ok it does not meaning that answer is unclear

Comment: the question is not about images? You use the principle of chaining but dont explain it. Furthermore geeksall is facing the problem that his task abruptly (so it appears) stops and cannot locate the problem. Can you explain how your answer helps with this?

Comment: @DGRFDSGN: I did it and this is not a way to promote or degrade any answer. you just requested to a person to add more explanation in code that may helpful to others.

Comment: @DGRFDSGN: If you have any specific issue with a code you ask us or me about my code, I should try to be specific.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136454/discussion-between-dgrfdsgn-and-dipak-chavda).